# Insert array (of objects) into mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, bulkinsert

I got working what i wanted by just doing the insert inside the 2 for-loops, but i felt like it should be better to do one insert after the loop is done.

What i tried:

**1: Insert array of objects** -> only inserts 1st object in array

```
  let itemsToDb = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < stashes.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < stashes[i].items.length; j++) {
      let item = stashes[i].items[j];
      let itemToDb = {
        item_id: item.id,
        verified: item.verified,
        icon: item.icon,
        name: item.name,
        typeline: item.typeLine,
        identified: item.identified,
        ilvl: item.ilvl,
        note: item.note,
        frametype: item.frameType,
        inventory_id: item.inventoryId,
        corrupted: item.corrupted,
        date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
      };
      itemsToDb.push(itemToDb);
    }
  }
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO items SET ?';
  db.query(sql, itemsToDb, (error) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(itemsToDb); //item added!
  });
```

**2: Insert array of arrays** -> Error (see below)

```
  let itemToDb = [
    item.id,
    item.verified,
    item.icon,
    item.name,
    item.typeLine,
    item.identified,
    item.ilvl,
    item.note,
    item.frameType,
    item.inventoryId,
    item.corrupted,
    new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
  ];

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''45580327d5e9aa29bac9f4461029acd59c379006cdd622a6290ce28bff3496ee', false, 'http' at line 1
```

Database structure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What's value `item.id` which you use in `INSERT`?. `id` is PRIMARY_KEY, if you've set autoincrement, there is possible problem with duplicities. If ypu have real `id` you must use `REPLACE` or with `INSERT` set value item.id to NULL.

Comment: item_id (filled with item.id)  is some unique hash i get from the API data. I don't need to add the id (a.i. primary key) to the array/object right? It will just count automaticly i thought?

Comment: Yes, it's right - I see it now. I mistake with names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parse_error message you may see that values are without column names. I don't excactly know about object params in node's mysql module. From reading sql error message you try INSERT with VALUES not SET:

```
INSERT INTO items (`item_id`, `verified`, `icon`, `name`, `typeline`, `identified`, `ilvl`, `note`, `frametype`, `inventory_id`, `corrupted`, `date`) VALUES ?
```

Comment: You got me on the right track. So indeed use VALUES and then [itemsToDb] instead of just itemsToDb. Tyty!

Comment: @Awesom-o: When you define sql db columns, make column's names more specific and don't use sql keywords - `date`. This column has some reason: `date_created_at` or `created_at` or somenthing else...

Comment: Makes sense yeah, i will work on that! Ty for the tip!

Comment: can I do this with mysql2 node package?